# How to extract entity using stanford parser?

Tags: parsing, nlp, opennlp

I am using OpenNLP but it is not giving me exact name,location,organization entity. How to extract entity using stanford parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code might help you.

Here is my Code

```
public class stanfrdIntro {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException,
    TikaException {

        String serializedClassifier = "classifiers/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz";


        AbstractSequenceClassifier<CoreLabel> classifier = CRFClassifier
                .getClassifierNoExceptions(serializedClassifier);

        if (args.length > 1) {
         String fileContents = IOUtils.slurpFile(args[1]);
        List<List<CoreLabel>> out = classifier.classify(fileContents);
        for (List<CoreLabel> sentence : out) {
        for (CoreLabel word : sentence) {
        System.out.print(word.word() + '/' +
         word.get(CoreAnnotations.AnswerAnnotation.class) + ' ');
         }
         System.out.println();
        }
 out = classifier.classifyFile(args[1]);
        for (List<CoreLabel> sentence : out) {
        for (CoreLabel word : sentence) {
        System.out.print(word.word() + '/' +
        word.get(CoreAnnotations.AnswerAnnotation.class) + ' ');
        }
         System.out.println();
         }

         } else {
        String s1 = "Good afternoon Rahul Kulhari, how are you today?";
         String s2 =
         "I go to school at Stanford University, which is located in California.";
        stanfrdIntro si = new stanfrdIntro();
        String s1 = si.contentEx();
        s1 = s1.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
        System.out.println(s1);
        String  t=classifier.classifyWithInlineXML(s1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getTagValues(t).toArray()));

        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//PERSON/text()");
        Object value = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
        System.out.println(t);
        System.out.println(classifier.classifyToString(s1));
        Set<String> s=classifier.;
        for(String s13: s)
        {
            System.out.println(s13);
        }
        System.out.println(classifier.classifyWithInlineXML(s1));
        System.out.println(classifier.classifyToString(s1, "xml", true));
         int i=0;
         for (List<CoreLabel> lcl : classifier.classify(s2)) {
        for (CoreLabel cl : lcl) {
         System.out.println(i++ + ":");
         System.out.println(cl);
 }
 }
 }
    }


}
```